# Dockerfile doesnt get the arguments passed from docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm unable to pass my arguments from docker-compose.yml into build

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  mail_prod:
    #env_file:
    #  - .env
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      args:
        - FROM_VERIFIED_EMAIL=sadasd
        - HOST_SMTP=asdasd
        - PORT_SMTP=asdasdsad
        - NAME_SMTP=asdasd
        - PASS_SMTP=iasdasdasd
        - AUTH_TOKEN_MAILSEND=asdasdasdasd
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG HOST_SMTP
ARG PORT_SMTP
ARG NAME_SMTP
ARG PASS_SMTP
ARG AUTH_TOKEN_MAILSEND
ARG FROM_VERIFIED_EMAIL

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD node server.js $HOST_SMTP $PORT_SMTP $NAME_SMTP $PASS_SMTP $AUTH_TOKEN_MAILSEND $FROM_VERIFIED_EMAIL
```

server.js

```
'use strict'

// Print the arguments which are passed
var myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
console.log('myArgs: ', myArgs);
```

This is what I get in output when I run the container:

> mail_prod_1     | myArgs:  []

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the docker-compose [documenentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/) - Args definition:

> Add build arguments, which are environment variables accessible only
> during the build process.

So one way I can suggest is to pass those arguments into environment variables for later use by your application (right after your `ARG` lines):

```
ENV HOST_SMTP=$HOST_SMTP
ENV PORT_SMTP=$PORT_SMTP
ENV NAME_SMTP=$NAME_SMTP
ENV PASS_SMTP=$PASS_SMTP
ENV AUTH_TOKEN_MAILSEND=$AUTH_TOKEN_MAILSEND
ENV FROM_VERIFIED_EMAIL=$FROM_VERIFIED_EMAIL
```

Comment: It worked that way. Accepting the answer, although I dont understand why ENV had to be used to make it work

Comment: from my understanding (and maybe I'm wrong) - the evaluation of the arguments doesn't happen in the build time and they do not exist in run time. BTW, the CMD command is wired, shouldn't it be `CMD  ["node server.js", "$HOST_SMTP", "$PORT_SMTP", "$NAME_SMTP", "$PASS_SMTP", "$AUTH_TOKEN_MAILSEND", "$FROM_VERIFIED_EMAIL"]`? (although i don't think it will change something)

Comment: Remember, anyone who has the image can look at its `docker history` and see these values in plain text.  This isn't a good way to provide passwords or tokens to the application.

Comment: So what is the correct way to do things @DavidMaze

Comment: Your process can look at _e.g._ `process.env.AUTH_TOKEN_MAILSEND` so you don't need to pass the values as command-line arguments, and then you can pass them in with Compose `environment:` at container startup time.